# Regex match a string that contains multiple substrings with each substring ending from 0 to fixed number n

Tags: regex

**String** -

`123|456|...|789 I am a long string with substring0 and substring1 also substring2 something more and end with substring3`

There are as many substrings as a fixed number `n` (eg. n=3 in this case). The first substring ends with `0`, second with `1` and last one with `n` i.e. sorted from left to right. Each `substring` is the same string. For example -

`123|456|...|789 I am a long string with abcd0 and abcd1 also abcd2 something more and end with abcd3`

How can we regex match such a line if the value of `n` is known in advance?

Sorry, I absolutely have no idea on how this can be achieved, hence didn't add anything more.

Thanks SO.

Comment: Suppose your string began `'120|'` rather than `'123|'`. Would that zero be the first match? Please explain why or why not. What if `'substring0'` were instead just `'0'`? Must `'0'`, `'1'`, and so on be in order, left-to-right?

Comment: No, the numbers are only appended to the `substring` keyword which is a fixed string. And it is always in order from `0` to `n` from left to right. I have edited the post with an example.

Comment: What if the string were, `"substring0 and substring7 and substring1 and substring2"` and `n = 3`?

Comment: With n=3, it is guaranteed that there will be only three substrings - `substring0`, `substring1` and `substring3` in that order from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- There are just as many substrings as **n** (and in order)

> *"With n=3, it is guaranteed that there will be only three substrings - substring0, substring1 and substring3 in that order from left to right."*

- You do indeed want to match the *whole* line;

> *"How can we regex match such a **line** if the value of n is known in advance?"*

---

Try something like:

```
^.*?(?<!\S)(\S+)0(?!\S)(?:.*?(?<!\S)\1\d+(?!\S)){n}.*$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dm7Ohk/1)

---

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `.*?` - Match 0+ (Lazy) characters;
- `(?<!\S)(\S+)0(?!\S)` A 1st capture group of non-whitespace chars followed by a zero nested between two lookarounds to assert a full word;
- `(?:.*?(?<!\S)\1\d+(?!\S)){n}` - A non-capture group to match **{n}** times 1+ whitespace chars and a backreference followed by digits nested in those same lookarounds;
- `.*` - 0+ (Greedy) characters other than newline;
- `$` - End-line anchor.